# install BIND9 AS A source RPMs

Tags: bind

I want to install BIND9 with its source code on Linux (CentOS 6.3), we know by using `yum install bind*` we don't get the source code, we get only the binary files.

Can anybody explain to me how to install BIND with its whole source code especially the `.c` files by using source RPM?

Something like this:

```
$ yumdownloader --source module-init-tools
```

Comment: Why do you believe that you need the source code?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abramsm, because I need to change the source code so I want to change it in linux after insatlling it

Comment: So then why do you need to install BIND *and* the source code?

Comment: how then can I change the source code of BIND9 and make linux take it as it changed not the original code @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: You would modify and then rebuild the SRPM.

Comment: how can I rebuild SPRM @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: I wrote up most of this on my blog in a 4 part series: http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/8156/centos-rpm-tutorial-part-4-another-example-of-rolling-your-own-spec-file/

Comment: You'll need to setup your own rpmbuild work area, install the SRPM (`rpm -ivh whatever.srpm`), then depending on your change (configuration options - make them in the .spec file) actual code changes you'd untar the tarball in SOURCES directory, make changes, re-tar it back up, and rebuild the RPM using the .spec file in SPEC dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to rebuild SRPM from the CentOS documentation: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM